# How to Persist Connection between RESTful Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a two restful webservices:

1. `getMarketData`
2. `stopMarketData`

`getMarketData` pulls the data from external service. `stopMarketData` will stop the pulling process of data being fetched from external service.

Now the problem is, when I fire `getMarketData` it creates a connection with the external service and start fetching the data (its continuous process as it continuously fetches the data until we call `stopMarketData`).

After that if I make a call to `stopMarketData` webservice it doesn't stop the fetching data process as the connection is not in the context of `getMarketData` so how can i persist the connection between `getMarketData` and `stopMarketData` calls in restful webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to maintain state in RESTful services.  How would you scale this  solution out to run on multiple machines or even multiple processes?

If you really do want to do this, you will have to somehow place the connection in a global area (such as in the Application object if you're doing JSP or ASP) that is available from multiple requests.  Then, the `stopMarketData` call could get the connection from that global area and close it.  This approach is definitely not very scalable.

Another option would be to use an asynchronous technology like Message Driven EJBs.  `startMarketData` and `stopMarketData` calls would simply post messages to these EJBs to start and stop, respectively.

Hope this helps.
Nate

Comment: Well is it possible to put the connection in global area using JAX-RS only as i am not using JSP ,i am directly generating urls